# Migrating existing field data to Channel Videos – anyone out there tried this?

Tags: devdemon, video, channel-videos

I'm looking to programatically migrate about 400 instances of "Video Player" field data to Channel Videos. All I have to work with is the Youtube/Vimeo video URLs. Wondering if anybody has attempted to do this or knows a clever way it could be done?

(Initial research has me thinking I could leverage *ajax.channel_videos* or an ACT url and write a script that sequences calls to the APIs using an existing hook.)

Comment: Please update this question if you have any success; I've also got hundreds of entries with text fields containing YT URLs that I'd love to migrate to Channel Videos.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an answer, but it's not exactly a solution: Don't.

Channel Videos maintains its own separate table in the database, with all sorts of metadata pulled from the video. From a future maintenance point of view, keeping things as a simple stored URL in a text field would be better... I've learned that less is more when it comes to DB structure.

I'd love to see someone create a fieldtype that has the ease-of-use of Channel Video's backend searching interface, but the DB simplicity of a plain text field storing a URL.